# Can MAXDOP be set for just a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure that contains many `SELECT` commands.

Instead of putting `OPTION (MAXDOP 8)` at the end of every select command, is there a way I can set it at the start of the stored procedure and remove it at the end, without actually setting it on the server?

ex.

```
sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism', 4
go
reconfigure with override
```

Comment: Why `MAXDOP 8?`  Do you have `max degree of parallelism 1` at the server level?  What's wrong with the stored procedure that you feel the need to add query options?

Comment: What issue(s) are you trying to correct by using this setting? I suspect there may be a better way if you can post more details (including code).

Answer (score 16):

I wish there was a way to set MAXDOP for the scope of the proc but I agree there is no way to do this.

To counter some of the advice above, there are great reasons for using the MAXDOP hint, such as for after hours index builds, updates or data builds in an multi processor environment, but where MAXDOP is set lower than the processor count to help balance activity during busy "peak" hours, such as normal business hours.  Unlike some hints, such as index hints, this will not force your processes to use more threads, but it will enable it to do so if the plan so chooses.

Some index builds will execute nearly twice as fast if you double the threads, so there is a genuine benefit.

Comment: [Plus 1] for recognizing specific edge cases which this option is beneficial.

Answer (score 6):

Sadly, no.

Your options are either set it at the server level using 
`sp_configure 'max degree of parallelism'`, or update each SELECT statement in your stored procedure to use `OPTION (MAXDOP 8)`.

That said, query options should be a last resort and if your queries are performing poorly, there may be an underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily no. The recommended way of doing such things is to not do them at all. Overwriting query should be only the *rare* exception when SQL Server truly picks a bad plan, not the rule. And when a query plan has to be enforced, the proper action is to use query plan guides:

- [Understanding Plan Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190417.aspx)
- [Designing and Implementing Plan Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189854.aspx)

The most important thing to understand is that query hints are *design* time options (they require *code* changes to modify the queries) and abusing them greatly reduces the future maintainability of the application (when hardware changes, or on different deployment sites, the hint will be wrong). By contrast query plan guides are *deployment* time options, they do not require code changes and can be customized on each deployed site, according to the on-site hardware capacity and workload.

Comment: Usage of any hints is rarely recommended, but we still have them available for one reason or another and you might want to think why ;) ... Sorry, but this answer is of no help.